# Problema al insertar secciones en un curso Moodle

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

Estoy intentando crear secciones dentro de un curso **Moodle** mediante un Script pero no lo consigo. Estoy utilizando la función `course_create_sections_if_missing` de Moodle pero no logro que se muestren las secciones en la web y en la BD están creadas.

El código que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

```
if($numSecciones >0){                   

    foreach ($secciones as $nombreSeccion ) {

        $idSeccion = comprobarSections($curso_moodle , $nombreSeccion );

        if($idSeccion == -1){                                   

            //creamos las secciones
            m("crear seccion: ". $nombreSeccion );

            $maxSection = getMaxSections($curso_moodle );

            if($maxSection != -1){                              
                m("max seccion: " . $maxSection);

                $idSec = $maxSection + 1;
                course_create_sections_if_missing($curso_moodle , $idSec);

                $res = updateNameSection($curso_moodle , $nombreSeccion , $idSec); 

                m("resultado update: " . $res);

            }else{
                m("el curso no tiene secciones");
            }

        }else{
            m("ya existe la seccion: ". $nombreSeccion );
        }   
    }
}else{
    m("No hay secciones para la comunidad. ");
}
```

Nota: la función m("") se encarga de mostrar el texto en la consola

la función **comprobarSections** es la siguiente:

```
/**
 * Comprueba si existe una seccion.
 *
 * @param $course id del curso.
 * @param $section nombre de la seccion
 *
 * @return id de la seccion
 */
function comprobarSections($course , $section){

    global $DB;
    $id = null;

    $sql = "SELECT id FROM mdl_course_sections where course = ? and name = ? ";
    $sections = $DB->get_records_sql($sql, array($course, $section));

    foreach ( $sections as $r ) {                       
        $id = $r->id;
    }

    if(is_null($id))
        return -1;
    else
        return $id;
}
```

la función **getMaxSections** es la siguiente:

```
/**
 * Devuelve el id de la seccion mas alto para un curso.
 *
 * @param $course id del curso.
 *
 * @return id de la seccion
 */
function getMaxSections($course){

    global $DB;
    $id = null;

    $sql = "SELECT max(section) as sec FROM mdl_course_sections where course = ? ";
    $sections = $DB->get_records_sql($sql, array($course));

    foreach ( $sections as $r ) {                       
        $id = $r->sec;
    }

    if(is_null($id))
        return -1;
    else
        return $id;
}
```

la función **updateNameSection** es la siguiente:

```
/**
 * Actualiza el nombre de una seccion.
 *
 * @param $course id del curso.
 * @param $nameSection nombre de la seccion.
 * @param $idSection id de la seccion.
 *
 * @return resultado
 */
function updateNameSection($course, $nameSection , $idSection){

    global $DB;
    $id = null;

    $sql = "update mdl_course_sections set name = ? where course = ? and section = ?";
    $result = $DB->execute($sql, array($nameSection , $course, $idSection));

    return $result;
}
```

Si alguien conoce cómo hacerlo o tiene algún ejemplo o documentación que me pueda servir, será una gran ayuda para mi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado la solución a este problema, hacia falta actualizar el número de secciones en la tabla **mdl_course_format_options**.

El código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
if($numSecciones >0){                   

    foreach ($secciones as $nombreSeccion ) {

        $idSeccion = comprobarSections($curso_moodle , $nombreSeccion );

        if($idSeccion == -1){                                   

            //creamos las secciones
            m("crear seccion: ". $nombreSeccion );

            $maxSection = getMaxSections($curso_moodle );

            if($maxSection != -1){                              
                m("max seccion: " . $maxSection);

                $idSec = $maxSection + 1;
                course_create_sections_if_missing($curso_moodle , $idSec);

                $res = updateNameSection($curso_moodle , $nombreSeccion , $idSec); 

                if($res){   
                    $idSec = $idSec + 1;
                    $res2 = updateNumSectionsCourse($curso_moodle , $idSec);
                }

            }else{
                m("el curso no tiene secciones");
            }

        }else{
            m("ya existe la seccion: ". $nombreSeccion );
        }   
    }
}else{
    m("No hay secciones para la comunidad. ");
}
```

y la función **updateNumSectionsCourse** es la siguiente:

```
    /**
 * Actualiza el numero de secciones de un curso.
 *
 * @param $course id del curso.
 * @param $numSections numero de secciones.
 *
 * @return resultado
 */
function updateNumSectionsCourse($course, $numSections){

    global $DB;

    $sql = "update mdl_course_format_options set value = ? where courseid = ? and name ='numsections'";
    $result = $DB->execute($sql, array($numSections , $course));

    return $result;
}
```